# Apply CSS on the parent element

Tags: javascript, css

Below is the html source that my application is generating.

[image: Without scrollbar]

```
<div id="xcp_columnvbox-1053-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 1210px; width: 1614px;">
    <div id="xcp_columnvbox-1053-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 1614px;">
        <div class="x-component xcpid_d3_workflow x-box-item x-component-default" style="width: 1600px; height: 1200px; right: auto; left: 5px; top: 5px; margin: 0px;" id="d3_workflow-1054">
            <svg width="1600" height="1200" pointer-events="all" id="wkfsvg">
                <rect class="background" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
                    <g transform="translate(105.72459429343519,80.37030244629102) scale(0.8705505632961247)">
                        <path class="link reject" d="M253.5984380214502,402.1890855465788L279.88016976277135,217.71424055243128"></path><path class="link reject" d="M319.40688436217283,627.4974326890339L258.6978412705136,444.27907127147273"></path><path class="link reject" d="M770.9526019432966,1041.799747984542L678.8002646503626,1008.9547951583202"></path><path class="link reject" 
                        ....
                        ....
                        ....
                    </g><defs><marker id="end-arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5L2,0" stroke-width="0px" fill="#000"></path></marker></defs>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On this div tag, I need to apply 'overflow: scroll' in the 'style' attribute. Below is an attempt using the Chrome developer tools -

[image: Overflow set using Chrome dev tools]

The challenge here is that, the id 'd3_workflow-1050' of this element is auto generated, so it could be anything. As a result, I cannot apply the CSS based on the id.

If this were a static id, I would have created a css like this -

```
#d3_workflow-1050 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

However, the sub element  has an id 'wkfsvg' and this is a static id. Can I use this id and apply the css to the parent div?

Comment: will you be able to assign a custom class to the said element... which library is used to generate the element

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give us text, not images, whenever possible. Images are tiny and hard to see, unless you explicitly go and open in new tab, and one can't copy-paste from them.

Comment: Looks like the element you are trying to target has a few classes which are probably always the same. Why don't you try target one of those?

Comment: Apologies for not providing the text along side images. I have done so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is created dynamically and the ID is dynamic then the best possible solution will be is to assign a predefined calss to the element like `d3-workflow` then use that for the css rule like

```
.d3-workflow {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

If that is not possible, then you will have to use javascript, but then you will have to makesure the script is executed after the elemetn is created like

```
document.getElementById('wkfsvg').parentNode.style.overflow = 'scroll'
```

or use you assign a class using javascript like

```
var el = document.getElementById('wkfsvg').parentNode;
el.className = (el.className || '') + ' d3-workflow';
```

If you want to support only modern browsers then

```
document.getElementById('wkfsvg').parentNode.classList.add('d3-workflow')
```

Comment: I tried using document.getElementById('wkfsvg').parentNode.style.overflow = 'scroll', but it doesn't seem to make an impact

Comment: I am wondering if my question itself is incorrect. Please refer to jsfiddle.net/gugr10ve/12. When I move the nodes outside the canvas (by dragging) or use the mouse scroll to zoom the nodes, I want a scroll bar to appear, so that the complete diagram is visible. Right now, nodes outside the available canvas are not visible. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to use jQuery:

```
$('#wkfsvg').parent().addClass('your-class-name');
```

and then add the corresponding CSS:

```
.your-class-name {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I would prefer to avoid jquery (if at  all possible) as there are a quite a few JS libraries already being used (Ext JS, D3, Cola). So would prefer to not introduce another one into the mix.

Comment: Well in that case, you could use vanilla JavaScript to do the same thing.  There is no way to target a parent element in pure CSS. If there is a set class name on that element, like some of others other replies have wondered, then obviously that is the best method. But if not, then you will have to use some JS.

Answer (score 1):

As a CSS-only solution, you can't immediately select the parent element. It's just not part of any spec, although many have requested.

It seems that the below class may be auto-generated by your app and might work:

```
.xcpid_d3_workflow {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```